# Wpf WebBrowser.Print() with arabic character

Tags: c#, printing, arabic

I am trying to use WebBrowser.Print() to print an html file which contain arabic character, the problem is that the arabic chatacter changed to strange chracter

Below are the html file code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content - Type" content="text / html; charset = windows - 1252" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border='0' style='width:300px;color:black;'>
            <tr>        
                <td colspan=3  align = center><b><font size= 4>القاسم</font></b> </td>  </tr><tr>       
                <td colspan=3>-------------------------------------------------------</td>  </tr><tr>
                <td colspan=2><b>1</b> بابول</td><td align = right>1.00 LBP</td></tr><tr>
                <td colspan=2><b>1</b> Biskrem</td><td align = right>3.00 LBP</td></tr><tr>
                <td colspan=2><b>1</b> تويكس</td><td align = right>1.00 LBP</td></tr><tr>      
                <td colspan=3>You Bought 3 Items</td></tr><tr>      
                <td colspan=3>-------------------------------------------------------</td>  </tr><tr>       
                <td>Subtotal</td>       <td colspan=2 align = right>5.00 LBP</td>   </tr><tr>       
                <td>Tax</td>        <td colspan=2 align = right>0.00 LBP</td>   </tr><tr>       
                <td colspan=3>-------------------------------------------------------</td>  </tr><tr>       
                <td>Total</td>      <td colspan=2 align = right><b>5.00 LBP</b></td>    </tr><tr>       
                <td colspan=3>-------------------------------------------------------</td>  </tr><tr>       
                <td colspan=3>القاسم Team .</td>    
            </tr> 
        </table>
        <br/>
    </body>
</html>
```

it should be looks like this:
[image: arabic output]

But when print it using webBrowser.Print(), it looks like this:
[image: print to pdf test]

Comment: You might want to capture an image of that character and include it with your question.  There' nowhere near enough info in the question for anyone to answer.  Is it one character (out of a bunch of arabic)?  Does the character look like a diamond, with, perhaps, a question mark in it?  In all likelihood it's a font issue.  Not all fonts include all characters.

Comment: i already edit the questions and include code and screenshot on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a good [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and other debugging details, it's impossible to provide a complete solution.

That said, the output you show is clearly a problem with text encoding. Your HTML shows an encoding of `windows-1252`, a character encoding that does not include any Arabic characters. So even though you've apparently entered Arabic characters in the HTML file, presumably using an editor that is treating the file as UTF8 where Arabic characters are supported, the *bytes* of the file will be rendered as if it's in the stated encoding of `windows-1252`.

The bytes that are supposed to represent Arabic characters will then be interpreted according to the `windows-1252` encoding, rather than the Arabic characters you expect. Because that's what you told the HTML renderer to do.

Most likely, if you would just provide the correct encoding name in the HTML, it would work. E.g.:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Note also that the extra spaces in your original HTML shouldn't be there. I've removed them in the example above.

For more information, see e.g. [Declaring character encodings in HTML](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations)

Comment: you are right, the problem was in spaces, when i copy the meta line VS add some spaces side to the quotes